# DNS Resoluition of Child Domain Workstation(s)

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have three domain controllers:

```
DC-01 = CORP.LOCAL
DC-02 = A.CORP.LOCAL
DC-03 = B.CORP.LOCAL
```

All three have replication set to *All DNS servers in the forest* and I can see all three zones in each controller's DNS consoles.

I've added a workstation, `PC-001`, to `A.CORP.LOCAL`, but I can't ping it from `CORP.LOCAL` because it's not resolving the name. What am I missing? I thought now that all zones can see each other I can ping all machines from wherever by name? On that note, `A` and `B` can ping each other and `CORP` by name, but `CORP` can't ping either.

I can obviously cheat with CNAMEs in the `CORP` controller, but that's just silly to do for all the machines I'll be joining. I'd appreciate any pointers on how to get this to work.

For reference this is a Windows Server 2012 domain and forest running on Amazon EC2.

Comment: Are you attempting to resolve the hostname only (i.e. single label name or short name) or are you using FQDN?

Comment: Yes, by using host names only. The FQDN does resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the necessary domain suffixes to the search list on all DNS clients (which is every machine; even DNS servers are also DNS clients.)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275553